# PostgreSQL Laravel not return id

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am using Laravel Query Builder with insertGetId method.

Migration with trigger. Trigger create new table for every user.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('links_group', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('users_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });

    DB::statement("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION links_group_triger() RETURNS trigger AS 
  $BODY$
DECLARE
    temp_users_id INTEGER;
    tablenew TEXT;
BEGIN
    temp_users_id := NEW.users_id;
    tablenew := 'links_group_' || NEW.users_id;
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM links_group WHERE users_id = temp_users_id ) THEN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || tablenew || ' ( id SERIAL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
CHECK ( users_id = ' || temp_users_id || '  ) ) INHERITS (links_group)';
END IF;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tablenew || ' SELECT(' || TG_RELNAME || ' ' || quote_literal(NEW) || ').* RETURNING id;';
RETURN NULL;
END;
 $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;");

    DB::statement("CREATE TRIGGER links_group_triger 
BEFORE INSERT ON links_group 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE links_group_triger();");

}
```

My problem is when using insertGetId data is inserted but ID not return.

```
$id_group = DB::table('links_group')->insertGetId($form);
```

Laravel throw error: 
ErrorException in PostgresProcessor.php line 20:
Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Can you post the code in your PostgresProcessor.php?

Comment: same as this https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/PostgresProcessor.php

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with 'return null' in trigger. If I change to 'return new' I have two same insert. I fix this with code

```
DB::table('links_group')->insert($form);
$id_links = DB::select("SELECT currval('links_group_id_seq');")[0]->currval;
```